# What's the difference between retire vs selective wipe in Intune Managed Device

Tags: macos, azure-active-directory, intune

I've enroll some devices with Intune, but **MacOs device cannot be wipe** since the "Wipe" button is disabled. I need to do **Selective Wipe**(Which is remove company data, but not the user data), can i replace it with **Retire** function? What's the difference ?

*What I've already tried :*
I've tried to restart the MacOs, approve management profiles from Intune, make sure the Device has been registered in Intune, but the wipe button is still disabled. I tried to call wipe from Graph API and it return 204 (which is success). But in Azure AD, Device action give notice : Wipe Failed.

Comment: Take a look. Follow the referred document will be helpful I hope.

Comment: If my answer helpful you could mark to help community. Thanks once again.

Comment: Hi @MdFaridUddinKiron ,  thanks to contribute this post, but I would like to wait a little bit more for another answer that may give another perspective for **Selective wipe** and Retire

Comment: Whats that? can you share, I would try to answer, What you exactly like to know?

Comment: I try to do selective wipe for Android and it directly sign out the device from Company Portal and restarting the device (not factory reset). The Android configuration still **remain the same**.  So I believe retire will do same thing, at least no more powerful than a selective wipe..

- I still believe I can replace selective wipe with retire, since.. We can't wipe mac-os device, the only option is **Retire**

Comment: You could replace it anyway, in that case consider these  1. `Configurations that were set by Intune policy are no longer enforced`, 2. `Wi-Fi and VPN profile settings will be removed`, 3. `Certificates are removed and revoked`, 4. `The management profile is removed`,5. `Email profiles that are provisioned through Intune are removed. Cached email on the device is deleted`, 6. `The Azure AD record is removed`. If is okay for you you could implement this.

Comment: Ok,, for while I'll keep your reply as an answer, but can you input "Selective Wipe" **instead of wipe** to clear ambiguity, because selective wipe does not restore a device to factory default.  Thanks @MdFaridUddinKiron

Comment: As per official document its wipe though, but for reducing your ambiguity I have updated it to selective wipe. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems you are trying to implement `Selective Wipe` and `Retire` on `Microsoft Intune`

As you know `both remove devices from Intune that are no longer needed`

**Difference**

You cannot replace `wipe` with `Retire` because their functionality is not similar. I have described below as per official statement.

**[Selective Wipe](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/intune/devices-wipe#wipe)**

The Wipe action restores a device to its factory default settings. The user data is kept if you choose the Retain enrollment state and user account checkbox. Otherwise, all data, apps, and settings will be removed

**[Retire](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/intune/devices-wipe#retire)**

The Retire action removes managed app data (where applicable), settings, and email profiles that were assigned by using Intune. The device is removed from Intune management. This happens the next time the device checks in and receives the remote Retire action

`Retire leaves the user's personal data on the device.`

> **Note:** 
>   Before you remove a user from Azure Active Directory (Azure AD), use
>   the Wipe or Retire actions for all devices that are associated with
>   that user. If you remove users that have managed devices from Azure
>   AD, Intune can no longer wipe or retire those devices.

For more details you could refer this official [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/intune/devices-wipe). If you still have any query feel free share. Thanks and happy coding!

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply, may you elaborate more why we can't assume both are same, because **selective wipe is leave the user's personal data** too in the device.

Comment: And I'm still wonder why Wipe is unapplicable for MacOs Device (in Intune) , can't found good reason for this over internet

Comment: @Wendi `wipe` is useful for resetting a device before you give the device to a new user its related to user where `Retire` related to  managed app data